# Apache Phoenix TableNotFoundException SYSTEM:CATALOG

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix, hortonworks-dataflow

I would like some help.
I formated my HDFS and I thought that Phoenix should RE-CREATE the tables of META-DATA in HBASE. But after that I got the bellow problems.
Anybody get the same problems?

**Error: SYSTEM:CATALOG (state=08000,code=101)**

```
org.apache.phoenix.exception.PhoenixIOException: SYSTEM:CATALOG
    at org.apache.phoenix.util.ServerUtil.parseServerException(ServerUtil.java:116)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.metaDataCoprocessorExec(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1323)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.metaDataCoprocessorExec(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1287)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.createTable(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1472)
    at org.apache.phoenix.schema.MetaDataClient.createTableInternal(MetaDataClient.java:2624)
    at org.apache.phoenix.schema.MetaDataClient.createTable(MetaDataClient.java:1040)
    at org.apache.phoenix.compile.CreateTableCompiler$2.execute(CreateTableCompiler.java:212)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$2.call(PhoenixStatement.java:393)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$2.call(PhoenixStatement.java:376)
    at org.apache.phoenix.call.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:53)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.executeMutation(PhoenixStatement.java:374)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.executeMutation(PhoenixStatement.java:363)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.executeUpdate(PhoenixStatement.java:1688)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$12.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:2444)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$12.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:2389)
    at org.apache.phoenix.util.PhoenixContextExecutor.call(PhoenixContextExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.init(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:2389)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.getConnectionQueryServices(PhoenixDriver.java:255)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.createConnection(PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.java:150)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.connect(PhoenixDriver.java:221)
    at sqlline.DatabaseConnection.connect(DatabaseConnection.java:157)
    at sqlline.DatabaseConnection.getConnection(DatabaseConnection.java:203)
    at sqlline.Commands.close(Commands.java:906)
    at sqlline.Commands.closeall(Commands.java:880)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.begin(SqlLine.java:714)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.start(SqlLine.java:398)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.main(SqlLine.java:291)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableNotFoundException: SYSTEM:CATALOG
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegionInMeta(ConnectionManager.java:1285)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(ConnectionManager.java:1183)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(ConnectionManager.java:1167)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(ConnectionManager.java:1124)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getRegionLocation(ConnectionManager.java:959)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HRegionLocator.getRegionLocation(HRegionLocator.java:83)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.getRegionLocation(HTable.java:505)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.getKeysAndRegionsInRange(HTable.java:721)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.getKeysAndRegionsInRange(HTable.java:691)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.getStartKeysInRange(HTable.java:1796)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.coprocessorService(HTable.java:1751)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.coprocessorService(HTable.java:1731)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.metaDataCoprocessorExec(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1306)
    ... 25 more
```

'